# How can I configure a Flutter TextField to take all text input?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text, flutter-textinputfield

I have precisely one `TextField` on the screen of my **Flutter** app. I want my Flutter app to both work on the desktop and on mobile.

Whenever the app is active I want all text input to go into the `TextField`. When the user clicks on the area outside of the `TextField` I still want the `TextField` to get all keyboard input.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: could you please show by adding an image to know what you really want.

Comment: can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh : What would you expect in a minimal-reproducible-example for the problem I described?

Comment: @Amirali Eric Janani: I don't care about how the image looks. I care about the behavior it has when I enter text.

Comment: A sample code that you've tried so far. and it will save N time of others.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean not closing the keyboard by clicking out side here is the solution:

EDIT:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _keyboardVisible = false;
  var focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      print("hasFocus ${focusNode.hasFocus}");
    });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('hello');
                 // Hide the keyboard when the user taps outside the TextField
                  if (_keyboardVisible) {
                    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
                    _keyboardVisible = false;
                  }
                  print("hasFocus ${focusNode.hasFocus}");
                },
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Tap outside the TextField'),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 16,
                left: 16,
                right: 16,
                child: RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  onKey: (event) {
                    // Show the keyboard when the user starts typing
                    if (!_keyboardVisible) {
                      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
                      _keyboardVisible = true;
                    }
                  },
                  child: const TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Enter text',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I'm clicking outside but the keyboard won't be hide until I click on Done.

happy coding...

Comment: In your example the TextField loses focus when the user clicks outside of it. And as a result further keyboard input doesn't go into the TextField.

Comment: So please tell me your problem in a clear way.

Comment: My problem is that when I press any key I want the input in my text field.

Comment: you mean that for example if you click on "Tap outside the TexField" text, your TextFiled being filled by that text???

Comment: Normally, if you click outside of the field, the TextField loses focus and thus doesn't receive the keyboard input anymore. Your code still does that.

Comment: I've edited the code and put some prints to know that the focusNode.hasFocus is true or false, please run this code and see what is happening.

Comment: Copy pasting code like this into https://dartpad.dev isn't complicated. The code still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm Sure that I'm still not understand what you mean, BTW please connect with me on Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/amirali-janani-957a611b0/ and I send you a Google meet link to see what you exact mean